# SharePoint 2010 Designer workflow starts but not executing action, how to fix this?

Tags: designer-workflow

I've a workflow attached to form library run with item created or updated. When item created, workflow starts and show status as InProgress but not execute any action. My first action is to send email but that itself not executed. This is happening for particular users and how to fix this issue?

Here is the workflow:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How long did you wait?  The default wait time for jobs to launch is 15 minutes (they are marked "In Progress" until the SharePoint Timer Service actually gets around to running the job).  You can reduce this to 1 minute in Central Admin.

Comment: It is not running for particular user only, for other its working fine. Could you please let me know which timer should set to1 minutes? thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's not timer, if its working for some users not others.   However, try the following: 

stsadm -o setproperty -pn job-workflow -pv value -url http://myWssServer

source:
http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/02/tuning-sharepoints-workflow-engine.html

Comment: Also, can you click "In Progress" and see if there are any errors recorded against the workflow that may help?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error found!